# Find the inverse of this infinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can anyone find the inverse of the following infinite matrix?

> $M=\begin{bmatrix} ^1 /_2 & ^1/_3 & ^1/_4 & \cdots\\
> ^1 /_3 & ^1/_4 & ^1/_5 &\cdots\\
> ^1 /_4 & ^1/_5 & ^1/_6 & \cdots\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
> \end{bmatrix}, \qquad M^{-1}= \ ?
> $

Comment: A (finite dimensional) analogue of this is the [Hilbert Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix).  There are clearly some differences, but it might be useful.  It also appears to be a [Hankel Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix)

Comment: This also appears to be a [Cauchy Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix), which seems to have an inversion formula (For finite dimensional matrices).

Comment: @Mark Is there any reason to expect that these inversion formulas should generalise to an infinite matrix?

Comment: No clue, I had just remembered seeing the Hilbert Matrix before, and that this looks similar.  I'm unfamiliar with infinite dimensional matrices though.